# Mongoose updateOne returns acknowledged false in NodeJs and ReactJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to update the user when he registers in my reactjs website using nodejs express backend with mongoose.

But whenever the route is posted my user document doesn't get updated at all.

I tried findOneAndUpdate() with the new:true option and it still did not return the updated document, it always returns the original document.

I am having a hard time understanding why mongodb does this and how to update a document easily without these errors/inconsistency.

Here is my code:

register user route:

```
router.post('/register', async (req, res) => {
    

   const {  name, username, email, phoneNumber, password } = req.body;

    try {

        let user = await User.findOne({ email: email });

        if(user) {
           return res.json({
               errors: [{ msg: "User already exists." }],

           });
        }

        const avatar = gravatar.url(email, { s: '200', r: 'pg', d: 'mm'})
        user = new User({ name, username, email, phoneNumber, avatar, password});

        const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
        user.password = await bcrypt.hash(password, salt);

        user.save().then( async (result) => {

            if(result) {

                const payload = {
                    user: {
                        id: user.id
                    }
                }
                jwt.sign(payload, "secret", {
                    expiresIn: 3600
                }, (err, token) => {
                    if(err) {
                        throw err;
                    } else {
                        res.json({
                            token: token,

                        });
                    }
                });

            } else {
                return res.json({ errors: [{ msg: "Registration Error." }] });
            }
        });

    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err.message);
        res.status(500).send("Server Error");
    }
}); 

router.post("/verification/send", async (req, res) => {

    const { email, name } = req.body;
    
    let verify_token = new Buffer.from(JSON.stringify({"email": email,})).toString("base64");
    
    await User.update(
        { email: email }, {
            $set: {
                verificationToken: verify_token,
            },

        }, {
            new: true,
        }).then((data) => {

                console.log(data)// logs acknowledged:false

                let emailObject = {
                    from: {
                        name: "name",
                        email:"info@info.com",
                    },

                    to: {
                        name: name,
                        email: email
                    },
                    subject: 'Email Verification',
                    html: "myhtmlfile",
                  
                };
                sgMail.send(emailObject).then(function (data) {
                    res.status(200).json({
                        msg: "Email sent successfully",
                        result: data
                    });
                }, function (error) {
                    console.error(error.message);
                    res.status(400).json({
                        msg: "Email not sent",
                    });
                });

    }).catch((e) => {
        console.error(e);
        res.status(500).send("Server Error");
    });
});
```

then in my reactjs Register.js

```
  axios.post("/register", data).then( async (response) => {
      console.log(response);
      if(response.data.statusCode === 200) {
        await dispatch({type: ACTION_TYPES.REGISTER_SUCCESS, payload: response.data});

        axios.post("/verification/send", emailData).then((result) => {
          console.log(result)
          if(result) {
            Toast.fire({
              icon: "success",
              title: "We have sent an email to your inbox",
            });
          }
        });
      } else if(response.data.statusCode === 403) {
        await dispatch({ type: ACTION_TYPES.REGISTER_ERROR, payload: response.data.errors[0].msg });
      }
    }).catch((e) => {
      console.log(e)
      console.error(e.message)
    })
```

Comment: You'll need to use `findOneAndUpdate` if you want to get the document back, otherwise you'll just receive an `UpdateResult` with the update status. Is `verificationToken` defined in your schema? It could be returning false because it's not defined or the token is already saved and unchanged.